# How to simulate ink-on-paper texture/feeling in line diagrams I make

Tags: texture, style, design-process, image-processing

How can I turn crisp/clean diagrams I create on my computer, into diagrams that look like these:

[image]

[image]

Notice how the lines are "coarse", they look like ink which has been soaked into grainy paper, they are quite imperfect lots of variability.

How do I apply such an effect to the lines over an entire diagram I may have created using straight-line, "perfect" rectangles, arrows etc.?

I don't know what the vocabulary for this is so it's been hard for me to research (and I am also lost now as to what tags to add to this question haha).

The only image processing program I have installed right now is ImageMagick, and I should have access to Affinity Photo. A solution using these would be the best for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were tasked with creating hand-drawn-looking diagrams, I'd use a library like [Rough.js](https://github.com/pshihn/rough) or [roughVis.js](https://github.com/jwilber/roughViz) to do so.

In your case this would require recreating the diagram using either tool but given your simple shapes it should be pretty straightforward.

For future readers, a similar hand drawn pencil look can be created using SVG filters. For more about that [check out this article](https://heredragonsabound.blogspot.com/2020/02/creating-pencil-effect-in-svg.html).

Post-processing-only avenues of manipulating the image you have into something hand drawn has a limit to how hand-drawn it can look. *Creating* them in a hand drawn way will give you finer control much more easily than doing post-processing effects.

Side note: For some basic input elements you could look into [Wired.js](https://github.com/wiredjs/wired-elements)

Comment: This is perfect for me, much more experience coding than designing. Thanks for the resources!